# How to disable docker container restart

Tags: postgresql, docker

Postgres docker is restarting with changed name after stopping it.
How to disable restart?

I've tried

```
docker update --restart=no my-container-ID
```

but when i stop container its starting again with new Container ID

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
53e52dfc9015        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours          5432/tcp            startmarketplace_db.1.o2i5ig3cn0tba5a64r4vkrb8n

$docker stop 53e52dfc9015

$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
a75d1587c66d        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   46 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       5432/tcp            startmarketplace_db.1.5ukdrwdo1bc0tssf4rzdkjrta
```

Source code of Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
    curl git unzip vim \
    libpng-dev libpq-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# xDebug
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
&& echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# PHP
ADD ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

# Apache
ADD ./virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
RUN a2enmod rewrite
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Source code of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    build: ./xxx
    ports:
  - "9001:80"
volumes:
  - ./app/xxx:/var/www/html
environment:
  XDEBUG_CONFIG: >
    remote_host=172.18.0.1
    idekey=xxx
  PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=xxx
links:
  - db
  db:
     image: postgres
     environment: 
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: what do you have in your `dockerfile` or `yml`? I suspect an always restart somewhere there. If that's the case you should force rm the container and adjust the value and start again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's running in swarm mode. You need to stop the service or remove the entire stack.

For just the service:

```
docker service rm startmarketplace_db
```

For the entire stack:

```
docker stack rm startmarketplace
```